# using jQuery variables in setTimeout

Tags: jquery, variables, settimeout

I'd like to use a variable for the millisecond parameter in setTimeout.

HTML

```
<ul>
<li>list item</li>
<li>list item</li>
<li>list item</li>
<li>list item</li>
</ul>
```

jQuery

```
var wait = $("li:last").index()*4000;
document.write(wait+'<br>');
setTimeout (argument.callee, wait);
```

The code should calculate how long to wait depending on how many list items there are and then repeat the code.  This should repeat infinitely.  I've tried many variants, they all create errors.  I'm sure it's something obvious.  Any help?

Here's the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/sZ3KY/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is **arguments.callee**, not **argument.callee**

Check this working **demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/sZ3KY/3/

**Code**:

```
var wait = $("li:last").index()*500;

function doIt() {
    document.write(wait+'<br>');
    setTimeout (arguments.callee, wait);
}

doIt();
```

Answer (score 0):

are you wanting to delay the printing of wait? if so use a function inside you time out like so

```
var wait = $("li:last").index()*4000;
setTimeout (function() {
    document.write(wait+'<br>');
}, wait);
```

Comment: yeah, sorry I should have specified that I wanted it to delay and then repeat the code infinitely

Answer (score 0):

The error isn't with the wait. The wait works fine...

```
var wait = $("li:last").index()*1000;
document.write(wait+'<br>');
setTimeout (function () { alert('Works') }, wait);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6e7kL/

The problem is that `argument.callee` isn't defined in your JS Fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

First off, don't use `document.write`.  It will clear the *entire* page, and replace it.  Second, what are you trying to do here?  What do you expect `argument.callee` to be here?

Your code works fine, if you give it an actual function:

```
var wait = $("li:last").index()*4000;
setTimeout (function(){
    alert('test');
}, wait);
​
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problems lies in the fact that setTimeout requires a function. See:

http://jsfiddle.net/sZ3KY/1/

```
var wait = $("li:last").index()*4000;
document.write(wait+'<br>');
setTimeout (function(){alert("I've waited "+wait/1000+"seconds before doing this")}, wait);
```

​